# Having trouble reading file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to read the certain file that contains data like

[image: data]

the use I code

```
import glob, os
# Current directory
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
print(current_dir)
current_dir = 'Users/Kann/Desktop/My photo'
file_open = open('Front body-LPT0014.txt', 'r+')
x = file_open.readline()
alist = []
for i in x:
  alist.append(i)
file_open.close()
```

I'm trying to make it returns the 2nd and 3rd columns but when I run the code it returns nothing

Comment: It means you get the first line and first value or not? Show your result.
Use  `alist.append(i.split())` instead of `alist.append(i)`.

Comment: Are you trying to change the directory with the line `current_dir = "Users/Kann/Desktop/My photo" `?   If yes, then it wont work. If no, then carry on

Comment: @visiblemanI  I was trying to open file from the directory outside python folder.

Comment: You don't need to add "solved" to the question title, and please don't edit the question to include the solution. If the answer below has solved your problem, simply mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Andrew answer will produce an TypeError because `append()` method only take one argument.
You can try following solution (just modify `append()` method arguments:

```
file_open = open('Front body-LPT0014.txt', 'r+')
alist = []
for line in file_open:
    fields = line.strip().split()
    alist.append([fields[1], fields[2]])

print(alist)
```

Or you can create a generator function for better performance, it's based on your purpose:

```
def get_data():
    for line in file_open:
        fields = line.strip().split()
        yield fields[1], fields[2]


for x in get_data():
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
file_open = open('Front body-LPT0014.txt', 'r+')
alist = []
for line in file_open:
     fields = line.strip().split()
     alist.append((fields[1], fields[2]))
```

Here, we are using the `split()` function to split each line of the file into a list of separate values (separated by spaces).

You say your code doesn't return anything, but returning only makes sense when you are writing a function, and your code doesn't define any new functions.

What do you want to do with `alist`?  You could display it, or write it to a new file, or process it in some other way.  But, if you don't do anything with it, you won't see any results.

Comment: It seems like no data was pushed in the array. When I tried `print(alist)`, no data was shown.

Comment: Thanks @loginmind for pointing out the mistake on the append line - I've since fixed it for future readers.